# Kotlin Generic Property

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way in kotlin to create a generic property **without** declaring a class level generic type? Something that looks like this:

```
interface Generic {
    val t: T //I need this type only once, thats why I dont wanna pass in the class level

    fun <E> gMethod(e: E) { //This works, so I'm wondering if there's something similiar to properties

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since the [documentation about generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) has no mention of such thing, I'm pretty sure this isn't a part of the language.

This is most likely because you have to declare the type of the property at *some* point. Generic functions make sense, because you call them with arguments that have some sort of a static type (or in the case of extension functions, call them *on* such arguments).

The question is, why would you want to have a generic property like this?

What would you expect this property to accept as a value when you're trying to set it? If the answer is anything, maybe its type should be `Any` or `Any?`.

The same applies for reading it - what type would you expect the value you're reading from this property to have? If you don't want to specify a type at all, again, it should probably be `Any` or `Any?`.

The solution that's actually in the language, that is having the class/interface take a type parameter, solves these issues.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a complete newbie to Kotlin, but a generic property is not really something wrong, is it?

What about this as a showcase. I do understand that this solution does not completely address your question.

```
interface BaseProperty<T> {
  var value: T
}


class IntProperty(var stringVal: String) : BaseProperty<Int?> {
  override var value: Int?
    get() = Integer.valueOf(stringVal)
    set(v: Int?) {
      stringVal = v.toString()
    }
}
```

Since the getter and setter of the property are also a functions, it would had been nice if I were able to specify T as generic type. I have tried to use getValue and setValue as generic functions and that seems to work, but not using the Kotlin property idiom.

Answer (score 4):

No, how should the compiler know what `T` is? If you don't need the generic type parameter `T` anyway, you can just declare it as `val t: Any`.

Comment: Maybe he want to insert a constraint on this Any type, like <T : String> val t: T

Answer (score 0):

```
    private val <T> List<T>.mutable: MutableList<T>
        get() = this.toMutableList()

    @Test
    fun demonstrate_genericProperty() {
        val numbers = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
        val mutableNumbers = numbers.mutable
        println("numbers = ${numbers}")
        println("mutableNumbers = ${mutableNumbers}")
        println("(numbers === mutableNumbers) = ${(numbers === mutableNumbers)}")
    }
```