# How to write lambdas with generics in kotlin?

Tags: generics, lambda, kotlin, type-parameter

I can write lambdas `id_Int` and `id_Boolean` with explicit type. And I can write function `identity` with type parameter. Can I write lambdas with type parameter?

```
fun testFuncInt(f: (Int) -> Int): Int = f(1) + 2

val id_Int = { x: Int -> x }

fun testFuncBoolean(f: (Boolean) -> Boolean): Boolean = !f(false)

val id_Boolean = { x: Boolean -> x }

fun <T> identity(x: T) = x

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(testFuncInt(id_Int))
    println(testFuncInt(::identity))
    println(testFuncBoolean(id_Boolean))
    println(testFuncBoolean(::identity))
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Kotlin does not have support for declaring generic properties without declaring that type at class level ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090011/kotlin-generic-property)), but you can do it using a function that returns a lambda corresponding to the desired type:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(testFuncBoolean(id()))
    println(testFuncInt(id()))
}

fun <T> id(): (T) -> T = { it }

fun testFuncInt(f: (Int) -> Int): Int = f(1) + 2
fun testFuncBoolean(f: (Boolean) -> Boolean): Boolean = !f(false)
```

Comment: "Kotlin does not have support for something like generic properties" I would change the wording of this, as this statement is incorrect. Nice and clean workaround, though.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for `suspend`ing functions because they have to be lambdas, not anonymous.  See https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/anonymous-suspending-functions/6000

Answer (score 2):

You can not write lambda with generics, **why** following paragraph taken from official documentation says it all.

> A lambda expression or an anonymous function is a "function literal", i.e. a function that is not declared, but passed immediately as an expression

A lambda expression or function is not declared, its an anonymous function.

But ultimately we do same thing by declaring function type as generic. We can pass a lambda expression that does the job.

```
fun testFuncInt(f: (Int) -> Int): Int = f(1) + 2
```

you can call it like: `testFuncInt{ a -> a }` or `testFuncInt{ it }`

So finally you are doing same thing (lambdas with type parameter), but there is no term like that as lambdas are expressions or anonymous functions.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you generally don't need to. A lambda has no declaration (which is kind of the point), so it's essentially an expression you can pass to a function, store in a `val`/`var` as you did when doing
`val id_Boolean = { x: Boolean -> x }`
but the type really gets worked out as it would in an expression.

The calls here will resolve to the correct type, since your functions takes a function that takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`, and a function that takes a `Boolean` and returns a `Boolean`

```
testFuncInt({ x -> x }) // x is an Int
testFuncInt({ it })     // it is the default argument
testFuncInt { x -> x }  // as top one, Kotlin's syntactic sugar
```

The important thing here is that the lambda expression still offers type safety, i.e. if you did something like this

```
fun <T> foo(x: T, lambda: (T) -> Boolean): Boolean = lambda(x)
foo(42, { x -> x })   // oops, lambda takes a T and returns a T
```

this will trigger a compiler error as `lambda`'s types don't match what `foo` expects, i.e. `foo` will pass an `Int` to the lambda and it expects a `Boolean` back. On the other hand, if you do this

```
foo(123, { it == 42 })
foo(123) { it == 42 }   // equivalent to above
```

The return type is actually deduced to be a `Boolean` as that's what the result of a comparison operation evaluates to and as 123 and 42 are of the same type, `lambda`'s types actually fit into what `foo` expects.