# Generic lambda or function value type in Kotlin

Tags: generics, types, functional-programming, kotlin

Given a function

```
fun <T> to5(x: T): Int = 5
```

is it possible to assign it to variable (value) `funVal` like this ?

```
val funVal: (T) -> Int = ::to5
```

without

> Unresolved reference: T

error ?

In other words is it possible to somehow tell Kotlin that `T` in `funVal` type declaration is a type parameter?

For example like this:

```
val <T> funVal: (T) -> Int = ::to5

val funVal<T>: (T) -> Int = ::to5

val funVal: <T> (T) -> Int = ::to5

val funVal: ((T) -> Int) <T> = ::to5
```

**Use case**

My use case is using currying with generics. Conceptually:

```
    fun pairStrWithStr(s: String): (String) -> Pair<String, String> = {
        Pair(s, it)
    }

    val pairStrWithAbc: (String) -> Pair<String, String> = pairStrWithStr("abc")

    pairStrWithAbc("xyz") // (abc, xyz)
```

Making the second argument generic:

```
fun <T> pairStrWithAny(s: String): (T) -> Pair<String, T> = {
    Pair(s, it)
}

// Compilation ERROR: Unresolved reference: T
val pairAnyWithAbc: (T) -> Pair<String, T> = pairStrWithAny("abc")
```

Of course I can provide `Any` as type:

```
val pairAnyWithAbc: (Any) -> Pair<String, Any> = pairStrWithAny("abc")
```

But then I lose the type information:

```
pairAnyWithAbc(5) // Pair<String, Any>
```

The solution I can think of are:

**Wrapping inside generic fun** (basically not real currying or high order function usage)

```
 fun <T> pairAnyWithAbc(t: T) {
        return pairAnyWithAbc(t)
 }
```

**Creating function for each type** (no using generics as I would like)

```
val pairStrWithAbc: (String) -> Pair<String, String> = pairStrWithAny("abc")

val pairIntWithAbc: (Int) -> Pair<String, Int> = pairStrWithAny("abc")
```

Comment: what is your use case?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 I added the use case

Answer (score 5):

Only classes and functions can have generic type parameters in Kotlin. If you really need a property to have a generic type, it has to belong to a class instance that can provide that generic type, like so:

```
class Foo<T> {
    val funVal: (T) -> Int = ::to5
}
```

There's more discussion about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44090011/4465208), I just can't flag this as a duplicate because that question doesn't have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [Object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html)

```
interface Fc {
    operator fun <T> invoke(arg: T): T
}

class A(
    private val used: Boolean,
) {
    val fc = if (used) (object : Fc {
        override fun <T> invoke(arg: T): T {
            println(used)
            return arg
        }
    }) else (object : Fc {
        override fun <T> invoke(arg: T): T {
            println(used)
            return arg
        }
    })

    fun <T> test(arg: T): T {
        return fc(arg)
    }
}
```