# Using Kotlin generics where clause for return type of property

Tags: generics, kotlin, properties

Is it possible to use the Kotlin generics `where` clause for the return type of a property?

If so, how?

I've used it for return types of functions, but can't seem to get it to work for properties, which leads me to assume it won't work with properties.

I need this because I have multiple hierarchies that my properties of my objects must implement.  I implement them using `<interface> by <class>` delegation composition in the class extends / implements clause.

The problem is that I want to expose a limited API of the implementation classes to certain code (rather than the full API), which I would like to do via limited interfaces.  The only problem is that, while I can use delegation composition for actual `object:`s, I can't seem to use it for just interfaces.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? I don't see how it would make sense for a property to need to define a type since you don't ever pass something to a getter, and if you have a generic parameter, you put the type definition in the class line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin Generic Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090011/kotlin-generic-property)

Comment: @Bananon: That isn't applicable for my use case, since I don't need the `where` for generics sake, I want it so that I can create a type without an explicit interface that inherits from multiple other types.

Comment: @XDR Sorry for misunderstanding you. I've posted an answer which explains when you can use generic type as a return type of the property.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `where` clause after the property type specification:

```
val <T> T.size: Int where T : CharSequence
    get() = this.length
```

Note that a property can only declare generic type that is inferred from its receiver because there is no syntax to call such property specifying type argument explicitly. Therefore, properties with generic parameters can be extension properties only.

Comment: I need to use the where clause for the return type of the property.  I'll update my question…

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the Kotlin generics `where` clause for the return type of property only if a type parameter can be inferred from the receiver type. Otherwise, there will be no way to specify the generic type on property use.

Examples:

1. `T` is inferred from Iterable type:

```
val <T> Iterable<T>.firstNotEmpty: T where T : CharSequence?
    get() = first { !it.isNullOrEmpty() }
```

2. Compile error - *type parameter of a property must be used in its receiver type*:

```
inline val <reified T> Iterable<*>.firstIntsanceOf: T where T : Any
    get() = first { it is T } as T
```